# Submit form via headless browser - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, headless-browser

Due to an archaic stack, the response from a form submission is HTML. When rendered on my clients domain, the relevant information is injected in via a portlet. If you render the markup locally, the necessary content is missing. This makes it impossible for me to simply post data to the relevant form endpoint.

As a result of this, I need to submit a form and scrape the success/fail page for the necessary information in a headless browser.

I'm planning on wiring an API endpoint in my NodeJS application that I can post the form data to which in turn will submit the form in the headless browser and respond with the scraped content.

Are there any frameworks that would support this? I've looked at Nightwatch and Web Driver but they all seem to be aimed at automated testing rather than what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [casper.js](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/)

It is a scripting and testing utility for use with [Slimer.js](https://slimerjs.org/) (headless browser)